# SSIS Derived Column nvarchar to bit

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a .csv file that has a column called *active* which contains values of 'Yes' and 'No'.

I have used the derived component within a SSIS package, but I'm struggling to get my expression working.  The field in Sql server has a data type of bit.

```
Active == "YES" ? "0" : "1"
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong ?

Comment: Take a look at this [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6aca0406-e0d6-4cb4-bcb6-d62897e61fa6/converting-dtstr-to-dtbool) you can also try casting your result to (DT_BOOL)

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there. This will work:

```
(DT_BOOL)(UPPER(Active) == "YES" ? 1 : 0)
```

So, you just use 1 and 0 rather than "1" and "0" (as you want numbers, not strings) and then cast the whole thing to a DT_BOOL, which will map just fine to SQL Server's `bit` type.

I've also added the UPPER, as you seem unsure whether your value is "Yes" or "YES", and the string comparison will be case-sensitive otherwise.

(Also, note that I've assumed you want Yes to map to 1 and No to map to 0, which would be the usual way around...)

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt get it to work like that either.  But this works..

```
REPLACE(REPLACE([Column 1],"yes","1"),"no","0")
```